# How to delete Windows Azure Git repository?

Tags: git, azure

I have a Azure Web Site that is linked with a Git Repository (in the deployments tab). How can I remove the repository and the link ? (I want to set up TFS deployment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there is no way to delete Git Repository link and set TFS again. for this you need to delete this website and recreate it, after that you can set up TFS deployment.

Comment: That's true. We're going to be adding it in the future.

Comment: @dfowler Thanks for your confirmation as I have checked this first time, as a end user there should be such feather to change deployment setting.

Comment: Like I said, we're adding it in the future.

Comment: @dfowler: This is the future. Has it happened yet?

Comment: There is a way to do this now. See the answer I just added for details.

Answer (score 10):

#### Updated answer (4/9/2013)

The Azure portal now directly supports doing this:

- Go to the Dashboard for the site on the Azure portal
- Under Quick Glance, click 'delete git repository'. Or if you were connected to GitHub (or Bitbucket, Codeplex, ...), click the 'Disconnect from Github' button.

#### Original answer

There is actually a way you can do this now, though it's a little manual. See the *Setting up continuous deployment from the portal after a deployment has happened* section in this [page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment).

Basically, run this from the command line, using the same username/password that you use for git deployment:

```
curl --user yourusername -X DELETE https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/live/scm
```

In the future, we will make this a simple action from the Azure portal.

Comment: Thanks. It's probably worth mentioning that `curl` isn't available by default and is bundled in [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/downloads) and in [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) - it took me a little while to work this out.

Comment: Thanks! After some wrangling with credentials, this seems to work. There was another initial moment of confusion for me in that this doesn't delete the content already there, only the association with source control. That seems reasonable, but I did wonder.

Comment: Actually, it does delete the repo and deployment history that's in there, but not the web root. How did you install git in a way that you didn't get curl? I always install msysgit, and it comes with it.

Comment: GitHub for Windows - but what I meant was that this doesn't add it to `cmd` or to Powershell - there's a `git shell` shortcut provided that I presume does some setting of environment variables. And when I said content I meant what I presume you mean by web root - the checked-out code and config. Evidenced by the fact the old homepage I wanted to ditch is still there. As I say, that makes sense now that I know what I'm getting.

Comment: Ah right. When you install msysgit, there is an option that lets you choose whether you want the tools to be available just in bash or system wide. Personally I use the system wide option and have never had problems with it.

Comment: This is now directly supported by the Portal. I updated my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an elegant solution ... and was able to delete several GB of data

1) login to new Azure portal

2) open the required App Service dashboard

3) in the left column there's a Console (in the DEVELOPMENT TOOLS)

4) back screen with command prompt opened

5) type:

**rm -rf .git**

Answer (score 0):

yes we can remove azure repositories from our local git using

```
git remote -v
git remote rm azure
```

thats it, it will remove azure git repo from the local git.